# Visual Studio 2022 - Publish database project locally, get message saying the Site.dacpac file is missing, and rebuild always skips

Tags: .net-4.5, visual-studio-2022, sqlproj

I am at a new role, and am trying to get started with the Visual Studio solution I will be working on - I am having an issue with the sqlproj within the solution - which is required to get my local instance up and running!
The issue is the publish step - I get the error "Could not find the file c:\Repos<whatever>\debug\bin\Site.dacpac.
Several different sources have suggested simply doing a Rebuild of the project, but VS always skips this project - even if I try a Clean first, or Clean the entire solution and Build after.

I have checked that the build is currently set to produce Debug code, and confirmed the project is set to be built in the Debug/All CPUs configuration.

Is there a way to force it to rebuild?

The only thing that I can think of is that the instructions I'm following request the developer to install SQL Server 2017, but I'd already installed SQL Server 2019 - could there be an issue there?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: for some reason the sql project didn't want to work with SQL 2019,
so I uninstalled that, and replaced with SQL 2017, and it worked.

I had expected '19 to be backwards compatible with '17, but apparently not.